# Tikz: draw above text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to use tikz to add some overlays, but they should appear above the text that is written after it, while for now it is behind:

[image]

I also tried to use layers but it does not help.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node(A){A};
        \node[overlay, below=1mm of A,fill=yellow]{Blaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{column}%
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      Blo
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
  Bluuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

To clarify, here is the output I'd like to have:

[image]

**EDIT**

Actually, I found (thanks to the idea of SebGlav) a workaround: just move the code of the overlay after the text I want to draw above. The problem is that it will work only if I know where is the page cut (or maybe if I can somehow inject my code to be executed before the next page cut). But it sounds a bit hacky (for instance because I need to cut my code, and I also need to use remember pictures that pollute the global namespace, and that I also need to find a new name for any overlay I need to draw…), I'm not sure if there is a better solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node(A){A};
\end{tikzpicture}

BBluuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[overlay, below=1mm of A,fill=yellow]{Blaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if that's what you're looking for, but if you want to draw underneath a text, `tikzmark` can do it like this:

[image: TikZ underneath text]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \fill[yellow] (pic cs:A) circle (1cm and 5mm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    I want to see the Ti\textit{k}Z overlay \tikzmarknode{A}{underneath} my words.
\end{document}
```

Comment: It clearly works, but I do not understand how. I believe that the manual states that for a `tikzmarknode` you should not use `pic cs:` but the normal coordinate system --- and for the ability to use the coordinate before it is declared, you need `tikzmark`(not `tikzmarknode`). What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks, but my goal is to do exactly the opposite: draw above the text. Basically, I want the `Blaaa` text/fill to be **above** the text `Bluuu` in order to hide it (the reason is that I want to label some parts of a pretty heavily filled slide, so I need to write on top of existing texts to explains the different parts of the slide). See my edit.

Comment: Actually, I'm thinking that I could just move the text that draws the overlay at the very end of my slide. It would work for this simple example because I know when the page ends, but it would not work on more complicated examples where I don't know where is the page cut. Is there a more generic solution?

Comment: @hpekristiansen: You don't miss anything, what you said is right, but anyway, a nice way to draw before the coordinate is defined is to use `pic cs:`.
@tobiasBora: I assume that you're still working on your larger project. Why don't you use `tikzmark` in the original way it was designed for?